# How to multiple a 2D point with a 4D Matrix

Tags: 3d, matrix, 2d, 4d

How can I convert a 2D point (or 3D with Z=0) to 2D point(where Z is ignored) with a 4D matrix ?

I am using Microsofts Silverlight to project a 2D control as pseudo 3D using a Matrix3D
[definition of Matrix3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.matrix3d(v=vs.95).aspx)

I know the initial 2D coordinate of a point in the untransformed control and I want the 2D position of the point after the transform.

The silverlight API is sparse regarding 3D methods.

Please suggest basic math to perform the calculation.

This is a follow on from a [silverlight specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017990/how-can-i-get-a-2d-point-from-a-matrix3d-in-silverlight)

Edit further details

its not working.
I am using

```
x = x0 * matrix[0][0] + y0 * matrix[1][0] + z0 * matrix[2][0] +
    w0 * matrix[3][0];

y = x0 * matrix[0][1] + y0 * matrix[1][1] + z0 * matrix[2][1] +
    w0 * matrix[3][1];

z = x0 * matrix[0][2] + y0 * matrix[1][2] + z0 * matrix[2][2] +
    w0 * matrix[3][2];
```

and the input x and y are 0,0 and the result x,y are 0, 58.5786
the matrix is

```
HasInverse  true    bool
IsIdentity  false   bool
M11 1.0 double
M12 0.0 double
M13 0.0 double
M14 0.0 double
M21 0.0 double
M22 0.70710676908493042 double
M23 0.70710676908493042 double
M24 0.0 double
M31 0.0 double
M32 -0.70710676908493042    double
M33 0.70710676908493042 double
M34 0.0 double
M44 1.0 double
OffsetX 0.0 double
OffsetY 58.578643798828125  double
OffsetZ -141.42135620117187 double
```

that produces a 45 degree angle rotation in Z where the rotation point is the bottom of the plane.

all the M1n values including OffsetX is 0.0 resulting in x always being the original value.

What am I doing wrong ?

Here are my four example values with the results of the above math

```
0, 0, 0, 1 -> 0, 58.5786437988281, -141.421356201172, 1
50, 0, 0, 1 -> 50, 58.5786437988281, -141.421356201172, 1
0, 100, 0, 1 -> 0, 129.289320707321, -70.7106792926788, 1
100, 100, 0, 1 -> 100, 129.289320707321, -70.7106792926788, 1
```

looking at the resulting image the 400x400 plane has a top left of 45,135 and top right of 355,135, bottom left is 0,400 and bottom right is 400,400

so for the test value of 0,0,0,1.0 I would expect x and y to 45,135

Answer (score 4):

Expand your 2D vector to a 4D vector - (X, Y, 0, 1); this is a 3D vector specified in [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). Multiply the 4D vector by the 4D matrix thus getting a new 4D vector, from which you take the first 2 components.

If the matrix specifies some kind of perspective projection, then you'll need to divide by the last component, i.e. if your resulting vector is (x, y, z, w), then the final coordinates are (x/w, y/w, z/w). If the matrix doesn't have a perspective projection, then w = 1 and the final vector is just (x, y, z)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a shortcut for this but what you want is:

```
newX = oldx * mat.M11 + oldY * mat.M21 + mat.OffsetX;
newX = oldx * mat.M12 + oldY * mat.M22 + mat.OffsetY;
```

(assuming that your oldZ is zero and you're going to ignore the newZ value).

Edit: A better way to do it is:

```
Vector3D oldPos(oldx, oldy, 0.0f);
Vector3D newPos = oldPos * matrix;
```

Your new coordinates are: `newPos.X` and `newPos.Y`;

Comment: @rob: What are the matrix values?

Comment: I posted a big long detailed response as an answer as I could see no way of adding the reply here and an admin detailed it.
Would have been nice if they could have checked to see if I was a new user and instead of just deleting it either left a note for me or added it to the question.
Details now added to the original question.

Comment: @rob, your matrix is translating by 58.57... in the Y direction (see OffsetY) so the output is correct. How are you generating the matrix - it looks like the matrix is not what you want rather than the matrix * vector operation failing.

Comment: I used the built in silverlight projection and then took the matrix it created but it seems to have the problem that all the X values are 0.

Comment: Can you provide me with a 4d Matrix that describes a plane in a 45 degree angle in the Y where the rotation point is the base, e.g. a large painting falling away from you.
Or a site that has the ability to generate such a thing, I would prefer to avoid the math.